# Issue getting started with Google Web Starter Kit

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

**What you need to know:**

I have Node, NPM, Ruby, SASS all installed and at lastest stable realeases. (ruby isn't at it's lastest stable but the lastest stable does not have the sass gem):

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2JHimBsITS6WHpCTmU4SXBQU28&usp=sharing

I updated npm by using the command line and following the guide on troubleshooting updating npm on windows **I USED OPTION 3**

I then went back to google's instructions for setting up the starter kit:

```
$ cd web-starter-kit
$ npm install
$ npm install gulp -g
```

I scrolled down and followed the steps to "Set Up Your Web Starter Kit Project" keep in mind that i renamed the folder from "web-starter-kit" to "google web" in this case for convenience

So i navigated to the starter kit folder using cmd (with admin rights) and typed

```
npm install
```

here are the results:

**See link to google drive**

**I still decided to go ahead and still tried to install gulp using**

```
npm install gulp -g
```

within the starter kit folder heres the results:

**See link to google drive**

Who ever helps me rectify this will receive my praise forever...I really want to be using this starter kit to start my projects.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/tkellen/node-v8flags/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to reference the **[install.md](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/install.md)** for the GWSK git repo.
 Looking at your install steps above, you are running npm install before installing Gulp. In the doc I referenced, it's Node.js, Gulp, then run the npm install inside of your project root.

I had errors when using the zipped version of GWSK that I downloaded from GitHub. When I cloned the repo with git, I had a error free clean install and no problems at all.

Cheers - D

EDIT:
OK, here is a step by step on the command line...

First I would have downloaded and installed node.js
Then I would have installed gulp (npm install --global gulp)

I'd then go to my web folder and clone the starter kit into a new project folder: "git clone https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit.git my_new_project"

The I cd into my new project folder and run: "npm install"

You should now be ready to work. While still in your new project folder run "gulp serve". That will start your web server, you can make all your changes in the app folder.

HTH - Don

Comment: I will try this out, yes i was following the instructions. No i don't know much about github cloning etc, you're free to share what you did exactly

Comment: Ok thanks, i originally tried this on a Windows machine will try it from a fresh mac machine. Hope i won't run into any hick-ups